# Converting Nim Enum to integer

Tags: enums, enumeration, nim-lang

Is there a way to convert an Enum (or string) to its int value?

```
type
    CarBrands = enum
        Audi, BMW, Mercedes, Proton

convertsEnumToInt[CarBrands]("Audi") # returns 0
convertsEnumToInt[CarBrands]("Proton") # returns 3
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [documentation](https://nim-by-example.github.io/types/enums/), you can use `ord` function.

```cs
type
  CompassDirections = enum
    cdNorth, cdEast, cdSouth, cdWest

for direction in ord(low(CompassDirections))..
                 ord(high(CompassDirections)):
  echo CompassDirections(direction), " ord: ", direction

var ordinal = low(int)
inc ordinal
dec ordinal
echo high(char)
```

Comment: The Nim Manual is clearer, IMHO: https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-enumeration-types

Comment: @xbello Feel free to edit the answer the way you think it's more clear or submit a better answer. Thanks for the suggestion.